# How to handle two inputs for two neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, anaconda

I want to build an architecture like this in Keras.

[image]

Here the output of 1D CNN (flattened) will be given as input to the ANN, and some other additional input will be given to ANN too. So there are two positions where this whole model will take input. How to handle this in Keras? In the `model.fit` function, we normally use one input. I am using Keras on top of Tensorflow backend and using Anaconda Python 3.7.3.

(Here ANN means normal neural network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras fully supports [multi-input models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models).

The way you do it is to use the [fucntional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and place two [`Input`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input) layers in your model. Build the rest of the architecture using the functional API and then define a [`Model`](https://keras.io/models/model/) with two inputs. During training you need to remember to feed both inputs in `model.fit()`.

In your case it would look something like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Flatten, Concatenate, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input1 = Input(shape=(...))  # add the shape of your input (excluding batch dimension)

conv = Conv1D(...)(input1)   # add convolution parameters (e.g. filters, kernel, strides)
flat = Flatten()(conv)

input2 = Input(shape=(...))  # add the shape of your secondary input

ann_input = Concatenate()([flat, input2])  # concatenate the two inputs of the ANN
ann = Dense(2)(ann_input)  # 2 because you are doing binary classification

model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[ann])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# assuming x1 and x2 are numpy arrays with the data for 'input1' and 'input2' 
# respectively and y is a numpy array containing the labels

model.fit([x1, x2], y)
```